# Synchronize drupal database with a traditional database

Tags: database

I have a installation of plain Drupal 6 with its own database. I have also another database,  different from the one used by Drupal.

I want to connect this database (with its own structure, tables and relations) with the database used by Drupal, and use the information in that database for creating views, for example.

I have a table "Persons" with 2 fields (*Name*, and *Age*) in the external database. I want to transfer (or connect, or synchronize) that information to my database in Drupal, or handle this information with some module. In my Drupal site, I have a "Persona" content type with two CCK fields: *Name*, and *Age*.

Is there any existing solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy answer: use the data module for drupal 6.x

http://drupal.org/project/data

"Data module helps you model, manage and query related sets of tables. It offers an administration interface and a low level API for manipulating tables and accessing their contents. Data module provides Views integration for displaying table data and Drupal search integration for searching table content."

The included data_ui module will let you setup the connections to your external database and map the fields.

Comment: i activate data_ui module and only i get that create a new table (admin/build/data) in the database of my drupal and extract the information of this table. ¿Where i setup my connection with my external database?

Comment: because i want to extract the information of my external database and put this in my drupal and administrate this

Comment: You want to add the connection to your external database in your settings file (see http://drupal.org/node/18429). When you loaded data_ui module, you also loaded schema which will recognize that the additional database doesn't match your existing drupal install and have these tables listed in the 'orphaned' tables section ready for adoption under the 'adopt tables' tab.

Comment: thnks a lot!.. But i find a ¿bug? in schema module because the mysql type date don't recognize... exist any patch for this bug?

Comment: not sure how to resolve that but there is a big thread (multiple threads actually) on schema and missing mysql date field on d.o: http://drupal.org/node/200953

Comment: uuhmm ok ok i understand... but now i have a other issue. At this point, schema module recognize the external database, i adopt the tables and i have the information... When i go to create one view for show that information.. drupal search in its own database, but no in the external. So, i have the following error: "user warning: Table '[database_drupal].Hoteles' doesn't exist query:" .. I need another configuration or something like this?